# Can anyone help me with the perl script to identify an image is svg or png?

Tags: perl

I want to make a script which automatically finds the format of the image type, svg or png. I tried this but it isn't working well.

```
sub imgtype {
        my $file  = shift;
        my %types = (

            'JPEG'  => qr/^\xFF\xD8/,
            'PNG'   => qr/^\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a/, # different image formats
            'SVG'   => qr/^<\?xml/,

            );      
        if (-e $file ) {
            open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
            read($fh,my $head,11);
            close($fh);

            while ( my ($type,$match) = each %types ) {         
                if ( $head=~m/$match/ ) {
                    return $type;               
                }
            }
            return undef;
        }else{
            return undef;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it isn't working well"? Do you get an error, does it detect the wrong type?

Comment: Or you could just use [`File::Type`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Type/lib/File/Type.pm).

Answer (score 3):

You already store regular expressions in the hash values of %types, so when you do the matching, just replace

```
if ( $head =~ m/$match/ ) {
```

with

```
if ( $head =~ $match ) {
```

that should work.

UPDATE:

I've refactored it a bit and added tests and `use strict` and `use warnings`.
But let's first create some images so we can test on them(note that `convert` is part of the [Imagemagick package](http://www.imagemagick.org/))

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font Arial-Regular -pointsize 72 label:Perl real.svg
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font Arial-Regular -pointsize 72 label:Perl real.png
convert -background lightblue -fill blue -font Arial-Regular -pointsize 72 label:Perl real.jpeg
echo "not really" > fake.png
echo "not really" > fake.jpeg
echo "not really" > fake.svg
```

Here is the refactored version of the code, including tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
sub imgtype {
    my $file  = shift;
    my %types = (
        'JPEG'  => qr/^\xFF\xD8/,
        'PNG'   => qr/^\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a/, # different image formats
        'SVG'   => qr/^<\?xml/,
    );      
    if (-e $file ) {
        open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die $!;
        read($fh,my $head,11);
        close($fh);

        while ( my ($type,$match) = each %types ) {
            return $type if $head=~ $match;
        }
    };
    return undef;
}

is(imgtype("real.jpeg"),"JPEG","true jpeg");
is(imgtype("fake.jpeg"),undef ,"fake jpeg");
is(imgtype("real.png" ),"PNG" ,"true png");
is(imgtype("fake.png" ),undef ,"fake png");
is(imgtype("real.svg" ),"SVG" ,"true svg");
is(imgtype("fake.svg" ),undef ,"fake svg");

done_testing;
```

After running it you'll get the following test output:

```
ok 1 - true jpeg
ok 2 - fake jpeg
ok 3 - true png
ok 4 - fake png
ok 5 - true svg
ok 6 - fake svg
1..6
```

All tests pass, so it works. However I would also recommend looking at the [file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) utility which is commonly used for recognizing the type of data contained in a file. The [File::Type](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Type) module which [Lee Duhem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004301/lee-duhem) mentioned is also a good fit for this, and there is also [File::LibMagic](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::LibMagic) and [File::MMagic](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::MMagic)

Answer (score 1):

You can usually find the type of a file using reading first few bytes in the file. For example, an SVG image is an XML document and should start with `<?xml`, while a PNG image should start with the bytes `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a` (in hex).

Instead of writing your own file type detector you can use an existing module, such as [File::Type](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aType)

Comment: OK, when I answered there was no code. What's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: While running this perl script its not throwing the exact output.